# How can I define Unicode characters in PHP using ASCII only?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, html-entities

Since our PHP code is running on different environments, we do not control (and we don't know the encoding of), the idea is to not use any none-ASCII characters in the source code.

However there are a few places in the code, where string literals are defined that contain none-ASCII characters, like 'TextWithÜ'.

Is there a way to write the 'Ü' using ASCII only?

The best I can think of is to use HTML-notation and decode it.

```
html_entity_decode('TextWith&Uuml;');
```

However, since we do not know the systems default encoding, I would have to detect that as well:

```
html_entity_decode('TextWith&Uuml;', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, ini_get('default_charset'));
```

And [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) supports only a subset of `ini_get('default_charset')` which is why that might fail sometimes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear to me what exactly you're concerned about. Can you clarify what exactly you don't control in these environments and where you may see failures due to encoding problems?

Comment: first of all, that is bad idea to use ASCII you should better use UTF-8. sorry but imho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you're shipping the source code files, you do control their encoding. If you save your files in UTF-8 encoding, [all string literals inside that file will be UTF-8 encoded](http://kunststube.net/encoding). One would have to purposefully convert the encoding of the file to change that, that hardly happens by accident or some misconfiguration.
2. If you're still concerned about this, the best way is probably to express the strings directly as bytes:

   ```
   $str = "TextWith\xC3\x9C"; // "Ü"
   ```

   This will be somewhat cumbersome to both write and read, but is the most direct way to system-agnostically produce strings with content in a specific encoding.

Assuming you're running your files as included files in another app, and your concern is that you don't know what encoding that other app expects, you would create an "encoding sandwich". Your code is in the middle and uses one standardised encoding (preferably UTF-8), with the "edges" converting to and from whatever the other surrounding code expects. That means you need defined borders, defined functions which the other code interacts with. On all input points, you do something like:

```
function take_input($input) {
    $input = iconv(App::externalEncoding(), 'UTF-8', $input);
    ...
}
```

At all points which return data to other code, you'd do:

```
function return_output() {
    ...
    return iconv('UTF-8', App::externalEncoding(), $output);
}
```

From the other app's point of view, that would look something like:

```
require_once 'JochensCode.php';

App::externalEncoding('SJIS');

take_input('文字化け');
echo return_output();
```